# Calling UDP function Automatically

Tags: c, udp, texas-instruments, openthread

I am using cli_ftd (Thread) example from TI Resource explorer(TI cc1352R).

I would like to call the UDP functions(i.e `open`, `bind`, `connect`, `send`) automatically at the booting time of the device(My thread network starts at boot time without using CLI ), 
so that I don't have to use the Command line(CLI).

I am not able to understand how to modify the project to do the aforementioned.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code I've written as part of my Bsc for CC2538: https://github.com/VictorAtPL/openthread/blob/thesis-final/examples/apps/pp_4/main.c

There is a function that starts up UDP server and a handler which responds for an UDP datagram.

Please also track what changes have I made in comparison to master branch.

If you want further help, please upload your code somewhere and specify what works as you do not expect.

Comment: Hi Victor, 
 First of all sorry for late reply and thank you for your suggestion. I referred your code and tried to implement it in thermostat example of TI cc1352R (thermostat.c) but I am still facing some issues with UDP open function. So can you please share your email id so that I can share my code?

Comment: It would be the best if you had uploaded the code to github's gist and share a link to it here, so others could also benefit from our discussion.